# Netbeans 11.3 is unable to download plugins or connect to the network

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Apache Netbeans 11.3 on Windows 10 (32 bit) with JDK8 (openjdk "1.8.0_40"). As I started to create my first Standard Java Project, it returned an error saying following plugin must be installed:

- `The nb-javac Java editing support library`

But as I tried to install the same from Tools=>Plugins menu, I got the below error:

[image: nb plugins network error]

When I went to Tools=>Options and tried "Test connection", that returned a connection error too:

[image: nb network test error]

I suspect this must be probably related to my windows firewall settings, though I've already shortlisted `netbeans.exe`, `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` in my firewall settings. I also tried manually downloading that exact jar file NB is trying to download (`https://netbeans.osuosl.org/binaries/34E9F9C1BDC61FE7EFCCF305D70960B862DE7815-nb-javac-13-impl.jar`) but even that didn't work. When I go to Plugins=>Downloaded tab=>Add Plugins and browse that file, NB won't recognize it.

How can I resolve this? My objective is to just install this plugin and get going with my Java learning agenda. Be it through the auto-installer or a way of manually getting NB to recognize this file, both are fine.

Comment: Since this is clearly a firewall issue, a workaround is to turn off your firewall for a few seconds to get _nb-javac_ installed, because you definitely need it for NetBeans with JDK 8. Alternatively, upgrade to JDK 9  or later, where installing _nb-javac_  is not essential. See [What's "nb-javac" in Apache NetBeans?](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-nb-javac-in) for clarification. All that said, there are several newer releases of both NetBeans and Java, so it would be much better to use more recent releases of both (if that is possible for you).

Comment: I also tried by turning off the firewall, even that didn't work with Netbeans 11.3. What did work was upgrading to version 12 but even there I faced issues as it needed additional `cacerts` in `jre/lib/security/` directory. Sadly, I have a 32 bit windows laptop where JDK8 is the latest one supported, all the above versions require 64 bit windows.

Comment: There is [a NetBeans plugin for 12.0 which might help](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=20) with your certificate issue. If a connection fails _"this plugin intercepts and prompts the user if the connection should be established regardless"_. Note that the plugin understandably comes with a warning in bold font: __"Using this module should be a last resort - fixing the certificate is preferred!"__, so be careful if you choose to try it. There is also a version for NetBeans 11, and you might be able to use that one to diagnose what you need to adjust in your firewall settings.

Comment: Wow, sounds like a good plugin, thanks! For now, I've paved my way by manually installing the certs for those few plugin sites [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66889979/849365) but this sounds good.